How to restore a scroll position while navigating back in angular 17
I am using Angular 17 to display a product list and I am trying to navigate back to list page from details page.
I am having one parent component and inside this parent component, i have child component as list components. After navigating to details page I am coming back to list page but scroll is always in the top but i want this scroll position to be retained in the last scrolled position.
